# Kubernetes unable delete images on mac/ docker unable remove images

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes

I read before questions like [Unable to delete all pods in Kubernetes - Clear/restart Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56867829) or https://stackoverflow.com/q

Someone says it is a duplicate, but **its answers aren't working for me**!

I'm trying to delete images:

```sh
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ % docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c0fe6040a78c        1d0a3365fc79        "/usr/sbin/nginx -g …"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            k8s_nginx_nginx1_default_485fea96-b84c-4713-bcf7-38d2a48e612b_3
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ % docker system prune -a
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all images without at least one container associated to them
  - all build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ % docker system prune -a
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all images without at least one container associated to them
  - all build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ % docker rmi -f 1d0a3365fc79
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 1d0a3365fc79 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container c0fe6040a78c
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

Again:

```sh
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ % docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q --filter "name=k8s")
c0fe6040a78c
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ % docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c752de53440e        1d0a3365fc79        "/usr/sbin/nginx -g …"   17 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds                           k8s_nginx_nginx1_default_485fea96-b84c-4713-bcf7-38d2a48e612b_0
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

I stop the container but unfortunately restart again.

```yaml
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ % docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
edacfbcb8a35        1d0a3365fc79        "/usr/sbin/nginx -g …"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_nginx_nginx1_default_485fea96-b84c-4713-bcf7-38d2a48e612b_3
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ % docker stop edacfbcb8a35
edacfbcb8a35
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ % docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ % docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
e2d695258f98        1d0a3365fc79        "/usr/sbin/nginx -g …"   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            k8s_nginx_nginx1_default_485fea96-b84c-4713-bcf7-38d2a48e612b_4
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

**Is there another method in order to delete the image and avoid auto-restart container?**

EDIT 1:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Unfortunatelly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you check all namespaces in Kubernetes to see if any pod is running when the container is running?

```sh
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

If not then you might have an [auto-restart](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart) on a specific docker container. In which case you can do:

```sh
docker update --restart=no <container_id>
```

Worse case you can go nuclear  and delete and reinstall docker on your Mac.

EDIT:

Looks like have a couple of deployments that are probably causing containers to restart `compose`, `compose-api`. You can try deleting them :

```sh
$ kubectl -n docker delete deploy compose compose-api
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, But I have the same problem. How do I check the Kubernetes restart options, not from pods/container?

Comment: delete your `compose and `compose-api` deployments. Sounds like that's docker compose and it's restarting your containers